# how to bind scene with stage in javafx2

Tags: javafx, scene

Actually I want to switch from one scene to another scene on particular event. So i can do that by setting scene of the stage without binding but i want to bind my stage with scene as soon as a flag changes my scene will change automatically....pls help

Answer (score 0):

The [JavaFX Demos and Samples Downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) contains an application called FXML-LoginDemo. It demonstrates how to change scenes in a stage. The important part happens in the method `replaceSceneContent`. As for automatically changing the stage when a flag in your application is updated, there are several ways to do that. I recommend using a [PropertyChangeListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html) or using JavaFX with[CDI](http://java.dzone.com/articles/fxml-javafx-powered-cdi-jboss) and then using CDI [events](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkhic.html). I used the latter approach in my application and it works really well.